# Disputing duplicate closure

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[This question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/59607/775) - which I will call "Question A" was closed as a duplicate of [Question B](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/49313/775), but I think it was done too hastily.

Question A asks for *a way to find out what user performed the last configuration on an interface*.  Question B asks only about `log config`.

Answers to Question A include TACACS+, which is not even a valid answer to Question B.

Please reverse this hasty decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YLearn reversed the closure.  Thank you, YLearn.